# Filter values from a Groovy List

Tags: groovy

I have the next list of arguments:

```
String[] args = [-s, http://192.168.0.3:8080, -a, admin:pass, -i, dev, /target]
```

I have to extract the url and user:password from this list.

```
array.find{ it.contains("http") || it.contains("admin") }
```

Is there a more sophisticated way to achieve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 def cli = new CliBuilder()
 cli.s(args:1,'url')
 cli.a(args:1,'credentials')
 cli.i(args:1,'env')
 
 String[] args = ['-s', 'http://192.168.0.3:8080', '-a', 'admin:pass', '-i', 'dev', '/target']
 def opts = cli.parse(args)
 
 
assert opts.a=='admin:pass'
assert opts.s==args[1]
```

another option:

```
String[] args = ['-s', 'http://192.168.0.3:8080', '-a', 'admin:pass', '-i', 'dev', '/target']

//collect pairs into a map drop single value 
def map = args.collate(2,2,false).collectEntries() 

assert map.'-s' == 'http://192.168.0.3:8080'
assert map.'-a' == 'admin:pass'
```

Comment: CliBuilder is deprecated

Comment: it's still available as https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/cli/commons/CliBuilder.html and you could still use the second approach

Comment: With the second approach I got the error message: Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.collate() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Boolean) values: [2, 2, false]

Comment: strange. maybe you have old groovy. try to apply `toList()` before collate `args.toList().collate(2,2,false).collectEntries()`